# Conditional comments not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added hconditional comments to IE8 but they do not work,this is my comment:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/lib/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/lib/Object.keys-polyfill.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modal-width.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

I have added alert messages to the `bootstrap-modal-within` file and it does not respond:

```
    alert("Inside conditional comment");
var link=document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href','css/bootstrap-modal-width.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link)
$(document).ready(function(){
    addModalWide();
    $(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
        var height = $(window).height() - 200;
        $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
    });
});

function addModalWide()
{
    alert("Inside addModalWide "+$modal.length);
    if(!$('.modal').length)
    {
        alert("Modal found");
        $('.modal').addClass("modal-wide");
    }else
    {
        alert("Modal not found,waiting 100 ms trying again");
        setTimeout(addModalWide,100);
    }   

}
```

Comment: So the other stuff for IE loads but not your script? Does this script that's not working have anything to do with the modals being loaded in the footer? I would think because conditional statements block download, it might be that the dependency is not loaded first. Often times, I use a modified boilerplate html doctype and write, inside the main script, if ($('html').hasClass('ie8')) { } or if (!$('html').hasClass('ie8')) {} NOT to just not load stuff. This works better

Comment: You could try loading that conditional for that script in the footer, after the other scripts, I've never done that before but it might work

Comment: @Christina did this(it worked): <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("Inside conditional comment");
       window.isIE=true;
      </script>

Comment: @Christina I find the `navbar-toggle` visible on IE8,`respond.js` has loaded though,I checked in the `IE8 dev tools`.